# TYPE_CHECKING imports helper module

Tags: python, types, import, python-module

I'm looking for a module similar to https://github.com/snok/flake8-type-checking,
That can automatically identify any imports which are used for typing only - So I could easily moved them under 'if TYPE_CHECKING' to avoid their loading and potentially prevent circular imports.

The problem with snook library is that its being supported only by later versions of python (3.8+), so i'm looking for alternatives - no success so far. Anyone knows something?

Comment: First thing, asking for library is off-topic. Second, python 3.8 supports win 7 and up, so why don't you use it?

Comment: If you *are* going to insist on using an earlier version of Python, you should at least tell us which one :-)

Comment: You right, I currently use 3.7.9. Its not for personal use, its for my work and we're avoiding the update due to backward compatibility with older libraries we use.

Answer (score 0):

[ruff](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/) has a wonderful mix of several linters. I found that enabling a couple rulesets will do what you're looking for.  Specifically [TCH](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/#flake8-type-checking-tch) and [ANN](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/#flake8-annotations-ann)

And ruff works in 3.7.  Though I will add, you might need to look at what limitations the linters have in that version of python.